# @IsTest - How to get the RestContext.response from @HttpPost if the post method is not returning

Tags: rest-api, apexrest, httppost, response

I created a @HttpPost API end point called `SampleAPI` that doesn't return an object. Instead I am populating RestResponse like so:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/SampleAPI/*')
global class SampleAPI{

    @HttpPost
    global static void verifyData() {

        RestResponse response = RestContext.response;
        response.statusCode = 200;
        response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('response body');
    }
}
```

In my test class I add the request body like so:

```
@IsTest
static void TestBehavior() {
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
    RestResponse response = new RestResponse();
    request.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/SampleAPI';
    request.httpMethod = 'POST';
    request.requestBody = Blob.valueof('test body');


    RestContext.request = request;
    RestContext.response = response;


    SampleAPI api = new SampleAPI();
}
```

How can I get the response body in my test method? I tried `RestContext.response` but that comes back as `[headers={}, responseBody=null, statusCode=null]` when I am actually expecting the `statusCode` and `responseBody` to not be null.

Comment: Looks like something may have gotten trimmed out of your posted code: `response = RestCoresponse.statusCode = 200;` was this supposed to be two separate lines?

Comment: @MarkPond Thank you. I think I fixed that. I can post more code if it's not clear enough. My problem is that in every article I read online the HttpPost method is returning a wrapper class. But I am curious how can I use the RestResponse body instead of returning a wrapper.

Comment: @MarkPond In the thread you linked the @HttpGet method is returning a string. In my case my method is not returning but instead is setting the `responseBody` on the `RestResponse`. When I hit the end point I get the `responseBody` but I cannot figure out how to get it in my test class.

Comment: @MarkPond I also changed my code to use the `addParameter`. Figured that one was wrong. But still the `RestResponse` is all nulls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call the actual http method for it to invoke the API and then if you check, it should have the response.

```
@IsTest
static void TestBehavior() {
    RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
    RestResponse response = new RestResponse();
    request.requestURI = '/services/apexrest/SampleAPI';
    request.httpMethod = 'POST';
    request.addParameter('test', 'test');

    RestContext.request = request;
    RestContext.response = response;

    SampleAPI.verifyData();

    //Now RestContext.response should have data returned from api call
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 2 minutes. Nice work!